# CS50 problem with check on Bulbs exercise, dysplaing a extra bulb on check but not on terminal

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

like i said in the title, having some problems with the check on the bubls problem, when I run the code on the terminal, the code run without a problem, but when it goes to the check it gets a bulb extra on the check, even if I copy and paste the input, on the terminal it has no problem, does anyone have any ideia on how to fix it?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int BITS_IN_BYTE = 8;

void print_bulb(int bit);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("What is the text?\n");
    int size = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int binary[BITS_IN_BYTE];

        for (int j = 0; j < BITS_IN_BYTE; j++)
        {
            binary[j] = text[i] % 2;
            text[i] /= 2;
        }

        for (int k = BITS_IN_BYTE; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            print_bulb(binary[k]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_bulb(int bit)
{
    if (bit == 0)
    {
        // Dark emoji
        printf("\U000026AB");
    }
    else if (bit == 1)
    {
        // Light emoji
        printf("\U0001F7E1");
    }
}
```

I already tried to change the signals on the for loops in a lot of manners and tried to hard code the variables, and tried to follow a tutorial in youtube, but in general it shouldn't have any problem in the code as far as i can see(which is not very far), thank you for your time!

sorry for any english typos and stuff like that, it's not my fisrt languague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop

```
for (int k = BITS_IN_BYTE; k >= 0; k--)
{
    print_bulb(binary[k]);
}
```

accesses memory outside the array `binary` when `k` is equal initially to `BITS_IN_BYTE`.

The loop can be rewritten like for example

```
for (int k = BITS_IN_BYTE; k > 0; )
{
    print_bulb(binary[--k]);
}
```